# Visualizing 1D data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a vector which gives the speed of a rat over time. Could someone please help me on how I can show this data with a "color map" or "color bar". Basically I want to show each data point with a color.

Comment: Did I answer your question @Mina?

Answer (score 2):

As what Suever suggested, using [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) is perfectly fine for your purposes.  You can also add in a colour bar to give meaning of the mapped colours to the values in your vector.  The y-axis won't have any meaning as you'll want to concentrate on the colours themselves.  Therefore, you'll want to blank out the y-axis by grabbing a handle to the current axes in the plot and just setting the y-axis labels to blank.

As such, do something like this assuming that your data is stored in the vector `data`:

```
data = rand(1,100); %// random dummy data - 100 element vector
imagesc(data);
colorbar;
set(gca, 'YTick', []);
```

We get this image now:

[image]

Note that the colour bar on the right is scaled using the lowest and highest values in your data.  The colours will be scaled so that it conforms to this lowest and highest value.